# Seminar listing for Joomla 2.5

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have searched the entire Joomla Extension Directory .But could not find a component which meets my requirments.

I need a joomla component for seminar listing.

To post seminars and Training. Visitor to the site should be able to post training and seminars(But publish after admin approval) .

I can buy commercial components also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could use a directory component like Mosets Tree. It allows visitors to post listings subject to admin approval and comes with all the usual category features, modules, etc. Each listing will have it's own dedicated page with info, email, gallery, etc, all of which are togglable.

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory/233

I think Sobi Pro offers similar functionality

http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/directory-a-documentation/directory/16649